# LinearRegression scala.MatchError:

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I am getting a scala.MatchError when using a ParamGridBuilder in Spark 1.6.1 and 2.0

```
val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
  .addGrid(lr.regParam, Array(0.1, 0.01))
  .addGrid(lr.fitIntercept)
  .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, Array(0.0, 0.5, 1.0))
  .build()
```

Error is

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 57.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 57.0 (TID 257, localhost): 
scala.MatchError: [280000,1.0,[2400.0,9373.0,3.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)
```

[Full code](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1221303294178191/1275177332049116/6190062569763605/latest.html)

The question is how I should use ParamGridBuilder in this case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem here is input schema not `ParamGridBuilder`. Price column is loaded as an integer while `LinearRegression` is expecting a double. You can fix it by explicitly casting column to required type:

```scala
val houses = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load(...)
  .withColumn("price", $"price".cast("double"))
```

Comment: thanks, missed that from the original example since there was no comment on why they casted to double

Comment: You're welcome. It should be validated based on schema not throw an exception in the middle of the job. Unfortunately ML is full of glitches like this.

Comment: Seems to work https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1221303294178191/1275177332049116/6190062569763605/latest.html

Comment: @oluies: how do you find is this issue related to datatype? I am getting similar error but I am not able to figure the root cause.
here is the org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 1712.): scala.MatchError: [null,1.0,(703,[107,347,350,359,389,397,400,402,403,455,688,696,697,698,699,700,701,702],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1,1.0,0.09963768115942029,0.2399878640776699,0.3333333333333334])] (of classorg.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)

Comment: I am using pyspark